Recursive Random Search and Categorical Cost Functions
I'm currently working on a project that involves optimizing the default Spark-submit configurations to minimize execution time. I've developed two models to aid in this process:
Binary Classification Model: This model predicts whether a given set of configurations will perform better than the default configurations.
Improvement Prediction Model: Using the output of the first model, this model filters out the better configurations and then predicts the degree of improvement over the default configurations. The improvements are categorized as follows:
Category 1: 0-10% improvement
Category 2: 10-20% improvement
Category 3: 20-30% improvement
Category 4: 30%+ improvement
Since the ultimate goal is to identify the optimal configuration, I'm considering using an algorithm like recursive random search. However, I'm unsure which categorical function would be most effective for this type of problem, especially since predicting the exact execution time is extremely challenging.
Additionally, I'm wondering if it's possible to incorporate recall as a variable in the cost function. Specifically, I want to use recall as a confidence indicator to help select the category in which I have the highest confidence.
Any advice or suggestions on the best approach to take would be greatly appreciated!

Maybe look into this sites tag [tag:experiment-design]
